# Save only RHS of equation

Tags: output-formatting, save

If I have an equation in Mathematica, say

```
f=a*x+Exp[x]
```

is it possible to save only RHS of the equation into a text or mx file, so that later I can load it and assign it to some other variable? **Save** seems to save the whole thing. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Try `Put` and friends

Comment: That's not an equation, an equation is of the form `f == a*x + Exp[x]`. If you store this equation in `g` with `g = f == a*x + Exp[x]`, running `g[[2]]` returns the RHS of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression

```
f = a*x + Exp[x]
```

is an assignment to the variable `f`, not an equation. If you save `f` to a file, you will be saving its value, which is exactly what you want.

Suppose you want the save the file to your desktop, then you could write

```
f = a*x + Exp[x]
```

> `E^x+a x`

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "f.m"}];
Put[f, path]
```

and retrieve it with

```
Get[path]
```

> `E^x+a x`